# How do I write a forEach statement as a Promise.all

Tags: javascript, d3.js, promise

I'm working on updating my d3.js map from v3 to v5, and running into issues with my `forEach` statement. Originally in the v3 version, I have a function that creates a dictionary from my csv data. CSV data has columns: **id**, **cases**, and **city**. My function was set up like this:

```
var promises = [
            d3.json("testdata/us.json"),
            d3.csv("testdata/county_dates.csv", function(d){
                cases.set(d.id, +d.cases);
            })
        ]

        Promise.all(promises).then(ready)

function ready(error, us, data) {
         var pairCaseWithId = {};
         var pairNameWithId = {};

data.forEach(function(d) {
        pairCaseWithId[d.id] = +d.cases;
        pairNameWithId[d.id] = d.city;
        });
```

I'm updating the code to use d3 v5 now, which uses Promises that I'm not familiar with. How do I update the `forEach` line to promises.all? I tried something like this:

```
data.then(function (result){
            return Promise.all(result.map(function(d){
                 pairCaseWithId[d.id] = +d.cases;
                 pairNameWithId[d.id] = d.city;
            }))
        }
```

Comment: Why do you need `Promise.all`? As far as I can see, you only have a single promise - that `data` where you call `.then`, so `result` should already be an array (I assume).

Comment: There is no reason to use `Promise.all()` unless you have multiple promises.  Your `.forEach()` loop has zero promises - it's just regular synchronous code.

Comment: are you using d3.csv to fetch and parse your data?

Comment: @cal_br_mar yes I am, like this


var promises = [
   d3.json("testdata/us.json"),
   d3.csv("testdata/county_dates.csv", function(d){
    cases.set(d.id, +d.cases);
   })
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Both methods `d3.json` and `d3.csv` returns a Promise. You can run it on a `Promise.all` and wait for the results.

```js
async function run(){
  const [usdata, county_data] = await Promise.all([d3.json("testdata/us.json"), d3.csv("testdata/county_dates.csv")])
  const county_data_processed = county_data.map(row => {
     // do something with row 
    return row
  }
}

run()
```

Comment: Thank you so much @cal_br_mar for helping me understand the logic bw async and promise! It's still a bit beyond my javascript understanding, but this was a helpful direction.

Comment: no worries, it's a bit confusing in the begging but then it's very powerful. There are different ways to use Promises, you can also use the Promise.then().then().catch() syntax. It depends on your implementation. If you run in the way above, it's more intuitive as you `await` waits until you have your data, then you can right way process it